# PHP Вывод объектов json

Tags: php

[".","..","emails.csv","fam.txt","files for your website should be uploaded here!","index2.html","name.txt","pay.php"]

Как вывести отдельно каждый объект методами php?

Answer (score 0):

Обычным перебором массива.

```php
<?php
$Arr = [".","..","emails.csv","fam.txt","files for your website should be uploaded here!","index2.html","name.txt","pay.php"];


foreach ($Arr as $k){
    echo '<br>'; // Перенос строки, просто для демонстрации
    print_r($k); // Выводим значение
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Да, сработало. Спасибо!